# Updating the value of the last one from repeating records within a week in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting data from a JSON file as below. I need to assingn 0 value to "Value" when if there is same value in the same week of year. How can I do that in LINQ ? For example:

```
INPUT

ID NAME         INFOID       DATE                       VALUE                           WEEK
2  AAA          31           1.11.2016 00:00:00         1,3                             44
2  AAA          32           2.11.2016 00:00:00         9,1                             44
2  AAA          33           3.11.2016 00:00:00         9,1                             44
2  AAA          34           4.11.2016 00:00:00         0,19                            44
2  AAA          37           7.11.2016 00:00:00         1,2                             45
2  AAA          38           8.11.2016 00:00:00         0,10                            45
2  AAA          39           9.11.2016 00:00:00         5,7                             45
2  AAA          40          10.11.2016 00:00:00         5,7                             45
2  AAA          41          11.11.2016 00:00:00         1,7                             45


OUTPUT

ID NAME         INFOID       DATE                       VALUE                           WEEK
2  AAA          31           1.11.2016 00:00:00         1,3                             44
2  AAA          32           2.11.2016 00:00:00         9,1                             44
2  AAA          33           3.11.2016 00:00:00         0                               44
2  AAA          34           4.11.2016 00:00:00         0,19                            44
2  AAA          37           7.11.2016 00:00:00         1,2                             45
2  AAA          38           8.11.2016 00:00:00         0,10                            45
2  AAA          39           9.11.2016 00:00:00         5,7                             45
2  AAA          40          10.11.2016 00:00:00         0                               45
2  AAA          41          11.11.2016 00:00:00         1,7                             45
```

The expected result should be above (output).

```
public class DataResolver
{    
   public void GetDataFromJson()
   {
     var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MarketData>>(jsonData);
   }    
}
public class DetailInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    public DetailInfo Detail { get; set; }
    public int InfoId { get; set; }
    public DateTime InfoDate { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Best Regards

Comment: You are looking for downvotes...Please try something and if you still have problems update the question

Comment: George Vovos I updated the question. I hope, the question is clear for you.

Comment: LINQ is a *query* language (hence the Q), not an update language. That said, LINQ can give you the last identical values in each week. Just group by week, order by date, skip the first and update what's left (if any).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem like that :

```
 public class DetailInfo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Info
    {
        public DetailInfo Detail { get; set; }
        public int InfoId { get; set; }
        public DateTime InfoDate { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }

        public int Week { get; set; }
    }

public List<Info> RefineData(List<Info> listOfInfo)
        {
            var orderedAndRefinedData = listOfInfo
                                    .OrderBy(p => p.InfoDate)
                                    .Select(p =>
                                              new Info
                                              {
                                                  Detail    = p.Detail,
                                                  InfoId    = p.InfoId,
                                                  InfoDate  = p.InfoDate,
                                                  Value     = p.Value,
                                                  Week      = WeekOfYear(p.InfoDate)
                                              }).ToList();

            var duplicateDataListInWeek = orderedAndRefinedData
                                            .GroupBy(p => new { p.Week, p.Value })
                                            .SelectMany(grp => grp.Skip(1));

            foreach (var dataItem in duplicateDataListInWeek)
            {
                dataItem.Value = 0;
            }

            return orderedAndRefinedData;
        }

        public static int WeekOfYear(DateTime date)
        {
            var day = (int)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(date);
            return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date.AddDays(4 - (day == 0 ? 7 : day)),
                                                                    CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
        }
```